# Replace String by another until the end of line

Tags: java, regex, string, end-of-line

I have a java string like this one :

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed
scelerisque enim a ornare auctor. Duis quam nisi, mattis vel leo eu,
luctus porta <img src="http://www.test.com" ...
```

I would like to keep only this text in the previous string : (without `<img ...`)

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed
scelerisque enim a ornare auctor. Duis quam nisi, mattis vel leo eu,
luctus porta
```

Could you help me to do this in Java?

Comment: Is this a single `String` that contains all the lines? Do you want to delete all tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the only string you given and that too `<img` at the end.

```
String[] strArray = string.split("<img");
String result= strArray [0];
```

Comment: @pXL yeah ..mentioned that also :)

Comment: @wawanopoulos you should go with this solution, it has the advantage that it won't barf if there are no `<img` in the input

Comment: mmm, you have right. Thanks for your help guys ! It's very interesting  to have a fast answer like this !

Comment: @wawanopoulos Glad to helpyou. Mark it as answer if you found helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use `.subString()` and `.indexOf()`:

```
result = string.subString(0, string.indexOf("<img"));
```

Though you'll need to check whether index is not -1 first...

Answer (score 1):

```
string.substring(0, string.indexOf("<img"));
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to delete tags would be

```
text = text.replaceAll("<[^>]*>","")
```

But I think it might need parsing as HTML and removing tags if there are more complicated tags with content inside.